# How do I make this code do a mouse over pause/play

Tags: jquery, slider, onmouseover

I created this slider code and I want to make it do a `onmouseenter` and `onmouseout` pause and continue.  I will be running a video in one of the slides and I would like for the video to play in entirety in the slider before the slider moves as well.

```
 // settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); 
var $slide = 'li'; 
var $transition_time = 1000; 
var $time_between_slides = 4000; 

function slides(){
  return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; 

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a sample? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) maybe?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/timlcooley/642Eg/25/ ]

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/642Eg/26/).

I have changed you code below `//auto scroll` comment:

```
// auto scroll 
$intVar = start();
function start(){
  return setInterval(
      function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides);
}

//mouse over
$($slide).hover(function(){
  clearInterval($intVar);
}, function(){
  $intVar = start();
});
```

*I hope it's what you need.*

Comment: Thank you I will check this out as well and see what I like better

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeInterval = null, transition_time = 1000, time_between_slides = 4000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $sliderLi = $slider.find('li');

    $sliderLi.hide();
    //$slider.find('li:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(transition_time);
    slideShow();
    timeInterval = setInterval(slideShow, transition_time + time_between_slides);

    function slideShow() {
        var i = $slider.find('li.active').index();

        $sliderLi.eq(i).removeClass('active').fadeOut(transition_time);

        if (i == -1 || $sliderLi.length == i + 1) {
            $slider.find('li:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(transition_time);
        } else {
            $sliderLi.eq(i + 1).addClass('active').fadeIn(transition_time);
        }
    };

    $slider.mouseenter(function () {
        clearInterval(timeInterval); //Or clearTimeout(timeInterval);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        timeInterval = setInterval(slideShow, transition_time + time_between_slides);
    });
});
```

Fro [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/642Eg/27/)